# Storybook in a NX workspace using UI lib

Tags: angular, storybook, nrwl-nx

My NX workspace contains several apps and libs. I am new to storybook and followed the commands here : https://nx.dev/latest/angular/storybook/overview to add storybook support. I want to add it to a simple component lib. The contains to angular modules, one of them is only simple module to import / export material components but the other module contains the components i want to test with storybook.

Creating everything worked fine, without any error. Starting storybook with the command `nx run project:storybook` ends up in some error message, all saying the same:

ERROR in ERROR in undefined(undefined,undefined):
TS5055: Cannot write file '/Users/ABCD/Documents/Development/git/WORKSPACENAME/.storybook/main.js' because it would overwrite input file.

...

ERROR in ERROR in undefined(undefined,undefined):
TS5055: Cannot write file '/Users/ABCD/Documents/Development/git/WORKSPACENAME/libs/core/components/.storybook/webpack.config.js' because it would overwrite input file.

What i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Well, i can answer the question by myself. I have found a completely different issue - so i thought - but it helped me here.

You need to define the dist folder also in the tsconfig.js and not only tsconfig.lib.json.

Comment: For clarification: ```"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",```